# Java server-client TCP, find minimum number in server

Tags: java, client-server

Task:
 1. I will write in clients printwriter       **min(2,3,4,5,6)**

> 1. this msz goes to servers buffered reader.

1. server needs to answer the minimum number and print.

how to deal with this  **min(parameters)** ,, server reads it as string.

to find minimum, i have to convert this **min(param.)** into a real arraylist in server.

Server code of how i did the date is given below, want answer in similar format.

```
if (msgFromClient != null && msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("DATE()")) { 
                    OutputStream clientOut = client.getOutputStream(); 
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(clientOut, true); 
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    Date date = new Date();
                    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
                    String ansMsg = dateFormat.format(date); 
                    pw.println(ansMsg);
                }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already answered your own question...

1. Convert the `String` into an array-based `Object`
2. Find the minimum value
3. Return the answer as a `String`

If you want help, give it a try first, post your answer, and then we'll be able to help correct any problems. We're not going to do your homework for you.